# Linux console can't display any language other than English while the terminal under Gnome can

Tags: linux, console, tty, unicode

I'm still new to Linux and Unix-like systems and I've tried to search on the internet about my issue. Unfortunately I don't get a feasible answer right now.

My problem is that the console(tty) on my Debian linux can't display any language other than English where it's a bit inconvenient for me as I have some folders and files on my disks with names in Chinese. When I try to locate the files in a terminal window of the Gnome desktop, however, it displays the Chinese characters for me perfectly. How can I get the file names displayed right in the console(tty)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Longer: the Linux console has *limited* ability to display Unicode in the console, supporting only 512 glyphs (which is a minuscule slice of Chinese).  The reason this is because it stores the information in (kernel) memory.  Furthermore, when doing this, it reduces the number of video attributes available (usually by eliminating "bold").

You can reportedly setup a framebuffer device, noting that few people discuss this in active use (it may not work well).

Further reading:

- [2. Display setup](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unicode-HOWTO-2.html) (The Unicode HOWTO)

  > In April 2000, Edmund Thomas Grimley Evans  has implemented an UTF-8 console terminal emulator. It uses Unicode fonts and relies on the Linux frame buffer device.
- [7.6. Configuring the Linux Console](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.3/chapter07/console.html)  (Linux From Scratch - Version 6.3)
  mentions the 512-character limit

  > Due to the use of a 512-glyph LatArCyrHeb-16 font in the previous example, bright colors are no longer available on the Linux console unless a framebuffer is used. If one wants to have bright colors without framebuffer and can live without characters not belonging to his language, it is still possible to use a language-specific 256-glyph font, as illustrated below.
- [How to display unicode in a Linux virtual terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/556993/how-to-display-unicode-in-a-linux-virtual-terminal)
- [Linux vconsole with utf-8 character broke when autocomplete #2602](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2602)
- [yaft (yet another framebuffer terminal)](http://uobikiemukot.github.io/yaft/)