# Linux console reverse is in low contrast

Tags: console, ncurses

Is it possible to change the contrast of the reverse mode of Linux Console ? I would like something in high-contrast, like pure black and pure white.

The current reverse mode uses a dark-gray as foreground and a light-gray as background, it's difficult to read what is in reverse mode.

Look at the text "Digite caracteres alfanumericos" in the image:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What application is this?

Comment: You could change the colors with e.g. `printf '\033]P7FFFFFF\033\\'`, but this will make it impossible to tell the difference between 'bold' and normal.

Comment: It's an ERP based in Unix multiuser terminals (pseudo terminals: pts). It's a Brazilian ERP (so, it's in Portuguese). It was coded in 80s and 90s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the program is trying to use "bold" + "reverse" modes, rather than just reverse. This results in "dark gray" on "light gray"

Without being able to change what the program uses, you can change what the colors themselves are. Dark gray is #8 whereas light gray is #7 (black is 0 and white is 15 (F), but you shouldn't need to change them) The Linux console has an escape code `ESC ] P n rrggbb` to redefine colors, so you can define them with e.g. `printf ']033]P7cccccc\033]P8333333'` to define them to colors that will have more contrast to each other, but still be distinct from black and white so that "bold" and non-"bold" text can be differentiated from each other. You may want to experiment with different values. Your picture has 808080 and cccccc, the supposed defaults (which I think may not be set on startup, but are reset with `ESC ] R`) on Linux are 555555 and aaaaaa.

Comment: Yes ! The program was setting `A_REVERSE|A_BOLD` and "`\e]P`" helped a lot.

Comment: Are there ways to adjust foreground and background colors apart ?

Comment: @Luciano No. If the application is actually using curses, and doesn't also use colors, you might be able to put something together with a custom terminfo entry that has sgr/rev/bold/etc use ansi color codes instead of the standard attribute codes, but that's a bit of a complex way to handle things.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that the "white" foreground comes out as **gray** because a *pure white* as you want is a bold color.  But using fonts that provide 512-glyphs as done for Unicode makes the bold colors unavailable.

Further reading:

- [Linux console can't display any language other than English while the terminal under Gnome can](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273061/linux-console-cant-display-any-language-other-than-english-while-the-terminal-u)

Comment: Er, the issue the OP described is that the reverse part is in gray (i.e. "bold black") instead of black.

Comment: It's the same number in the color palette.  I could quote the source-code, but that should have been unnecessary.

Comment: It might or might not be; there's no particular reason to assume whether the unknown program he is using is trying to use a bright background or not. And even if it is, fixing the foreground would go a long way to being more readable.